# Getting Wordpress Admin Select Value into Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'm working through the Ajax reference in the Wordpress Codex and adapting their example for an Admin side plugin

My plugin code creates a new dropdown in a Woocommerce product index page as follows:

```
$dmo_select = '<select onchange="dmo_service_update()">';
foreach ($dmo_service_enhancements as $enhancement) {
    $dmo_select .= '<option value="'.$enhancement.'">'.$enhancement.'</option>';
}       
$dmo_select .= '</select>';
```

Using the Wordpress Codex example, I can fire up the alert dialogue when the select is changed:

PHP:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
function my_enqueue($hook) {
    wp_enqueue_script('wtd-dmo-update', plugins_url( 'ajax-js.js', __FILE__ ),     array('jquery') );    
    wp_localize_script    (     
            'wtd-dmo-update',     
            'ajax_object',    
            array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), 'we_value_3' => 1234 )     
    );    
}    

add_action( 'wp_ajax_dmo_service_update_php_2', 'dmo_service_update_php_1' );
function dmo_service_update_php_1() {
    global $wpdb;
    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever_4'] );
    $whatever += 10;
        echo $whatever;
    die();
}
```

Javascript:

```
function dmo_service_update(){
    var data = {
        'action': 'dmo_service_update_php_2',       
        'whatever_4': ajax_object.we_value_3,     
    };

    jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
}
```

The problem is that the value processed by ajax ('1234') is hardcoded in the example provided in the wp_localize_script() function call which seems to set everything up.

What I need is the value of the selected select box.  How would I pass that into Ajax, rather than a hardcoded value?

Ultimately, I'm aiming to write the select value to the db using the dmo_service_update_php_1 php function.  Any pointers would be very gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `select` tag `onchange()` trigger to include `this.value`:

```
<select onchange="dmo_service_update(this.value)">
```

Accept the value into the javascript function

```
function dmo_service_update(dmo_selected){
    var data = {
    'action': 'dmo_service_update_php_2',   
    'dmo_selected' : dmo_selected
};
```

The PHP can now read the value as a $_POST parameter:

```
function dmo_service_update_php_1() {
    $selected = $_POST['dmo_selected'];
    die();
}
```